# ASP.NET Core Custom Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-authorization

I need to implement role based authorization on a .NET 5 API but the thing is that we don't want to decorate all the controllers with attributes and a list of roles, because all that configuration will come from either a config file (JSON) or an external service (TBD), in a way that roles will be mapped to controllers and actions and we would want to have something that centralizes all this logic, in a similar way we did before with Authentication Filters and Attributes.

I've been reading that now the idea from MS is that everything is handled with policies and requirements, but I don't know how to fit all that into our desired schema. Most of all because I don't see (or can't see) how can I access the Controller and Action's descriptors to know where I'm standing when I perform the authorization process.

Is there any way to achieve this on this new model?

**EDIT**: I found a way to get controller and action descriptors in order to do part of what I intended. Based on some other questions and articles I read and some tinkering on my own, I got the following:

```c#
public class AuthorizationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var descriptor = (ControllerActionDescriptor)context.ActionDescriptor; //<<-- this is the key casting :)
        var ctrlName = descriptor.ControllerName;
        var actionName = descriptor.ActionName;
        var userPrincipal = context.HttpContext.User;
        //DO STUFF AND DECIDE RESULT TYPE BASED ON USER CLAIMS AND CURRENT CONTROLLER AND ACTION
        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then I could add this filter the following way:

```c#
services.AddControllers(x => x.Filters.Add<AuthorizationFilter>());
```

This way I could achieve something similar as before with ASP.NET MVC 4/5, but from what I can read, the .NET Core team tried to go away from this path by implementing the `IAuthorizationRequirement` and `AuthorizationHandler<T>` mechanism to replace all that, so my doubt remains: is this the correct way to do it in the new .NET Core 3.x / .NET 5 architecture? Or is there some other way I'm overlooking on how to get and process the controller/action being executed and pass it along to an `AuthorizationHandler`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called externalized authorization also referred to as attribute-based access control. In this model:

- authorization logic is decoupled from the application
- authorization logic is expressed as policies that build on top of attributes
- attributes are key-value pairs that describe the subject, the action, the resource, and the context of what's going on (A user wants to execute an action on an object at a given time and place)
- authorization is decided based on those policies in a logical central point (logical because you could very well have multiple instances of that central point colocated with your app for performance reasons). That logical central point in [abac](/questions/tagged/abac) is known as the Policy Decision Point (PDP)
- authorization is enforced based on the response back from the PDP in the place where you want to enforce it. This could be at a method level or at an API level or even a UI level: you choose. The component in charge of enforcing the decision is called a Policy Enforcement Point (PEP).

There's one main standard out there called [xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml) and its developer-friendly notation called [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa) that will let you implement attribute-based access control. It's worth noting this model and approach is applicable to any app (not .NET-specific at all).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I was looking for more about the implementation details of how to resolve my requirement on .Net Core / .Net 5. I mean: is there a way to get access to the controller and action descriptors? Because the AuthorizationContext doesn't seem to expose anything about that... If so, how? Otherwise, what would be the alternative?